# Play video if all input field are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a simple form, I want to play an HTML 5 video when all inputs are filled and not empty.

Problem:

Check if all the form inputs are not empty if it's a true play video else do something else.

Here is my solution

HTML:

```
 <video  id="videoPlayer" playsinline controls muted>
 </video>

<form action="/action_page.php" class="form">
  Enter your name:
  <input name="firstname" type="text">
  <input name="lastname" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Js

```
<script>
var movieSendData ="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
var myVideo = document.getElementById('videoPlayer);

function playVideo(){
  myVideo.play();
}

(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).val() === '' )
          isValid = false;
    });
playVideo(movieSendData);
  })();

</script>
```

Unfortunately, my solution is not working as expected, what do I need to change to get what I want? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the src on video and you also need `if` check, you also need to iterate over inputs not on forms.

```
<script>
var movieSendData ="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
var myVideo = document.getElementById('videoPlayer);

function playVideo(src) {
  myVideo.src = src;
  myVideo.play();
}

(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form input, .form textarea, .form select').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).val() === '' )
          isValid = false;
    });
    if (isValid) {
       playVideo(movieSendData);
    }
  })();

</script>
```

this will run on init (if the form is not before the script tag it will not work, it will not found the `.form`) if you want to run on submit you need:

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('.form input, .form textarea, .form select').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).val() === '' )
          isValid = false;
    });
    if (isValid) {
       playVideo(movieSendData);
    }
    return false;
 });
```

if you get error that you can get value src on null then it mean that it can't find your video tag then you will need to wrap whole code in `$(function() { /* your code */ });`

**EDIT**: working stack snippet

```js
$(function() {
  var movieSendData ="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
  var myVideo = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

  function playVideo(src) {
    myVideo.src = src;
    myVideo.play();
  }

  $('.form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var isValid = true;
      $('.form input, .form textarea, .form select').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === '' )
            isValid = false;
      });
      if (isValid) {
         playVideo(movieSendData);
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video  id="videoPlayer" playsinline controls muted>
 </video>

<form class="form">
  Enter your name:
  <input name="firstname" type="text">
  <input name="lastname" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <!-- the input need to have a value or it can be a button -->
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tested Its not working, I think as u said about init, do I need to create an init function and add this function to it?, in real app I have separated these files form and js ,

Comment: @user9964622 what exactly is not working, do you have any error?

Comment: @user9964622 found the error the submit need to have value otherwise it will be input with emtpy value and it will not play. you can also fix this by changing `<input type="submit"` to `button` (that's submit by default unless you set `type="button"`)

Comment: is it possible to achieve what I want without submitting event?

Comment: @user9964622 yes you simply need normal button, input `type="button"` or `button type="button"` it will not submit the form. With this you will need click event or change/keypress on input.